# Edit field in content type after creation

Tags: 8, hooks

I want to edit a field from a content type after the content type is created.

I'm using `hook_entity_presave` to alter some things before it's saved and `hook_entity_insert` trying to edit a field that was created via the previous hook.

The code looks like so:

```
function hook_entity_insert(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity) {
  $node = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load($entity->id());
  $link = $node->get('field_evaluation_link')->value . '&qid=' .  $entity->id();
  $node->set('field_evaluation_link', $link);
  $node->save();
}
```

The hook is called properly. The problem is that it doesn't save the newly edited value in the `field_evaluation_link`.

I'm very sure that I'm not doing something properly and at this point I'm out of ideas.

Any pointing in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

Comment: As explained here https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_insert/8.2.x:
"This hook runs once the entity has been stored. Note that hook implementations may not alter the stored entity data."
Why? Because the insert is run in a transaction that hasn't been committed yet.